# How to make Perf work on React-Native?

Tags: performance, reactjs, react-native

Currently running Perf on React-Native yields error and the package seems to depend on the DOM. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html#using-perf

But still its mentioned in the React-Native docs?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#profiling

I have not succeeding in running it at least.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I found the similar issue, it seems to me `react-addons-perf` only work on `react`, for `react native` project, you can use `RCTRenderingPerf` which is a built-in tool in `react native` lib. My react native version is `"react-native": "^0.45.1"`

`import PerfMonitor from 'react-native/Libraries/Performance/RCTRenderingPerf';`

Start measurements

```
PerfMonitor.toggle();
PerfMonitor.start();
```

Stop measurements and print Results

```
PerfMonitor.stop();
```

You do not need to explicitly call print method to print the results, `stop()` already covered that.

You can verify it by running:

```
...
  _setIndex(idx){
    PerfMonitor.toggle();
    PerfMonitor.start();
    this.setState({index:idx})
  }

  componentDidUpdate(){
    PerfMonitor.stop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Welcome to react-native {helloWorld()}</Text>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Text>Changes you make will automatically reload.</Text>
        <Text>Shake your phone to open the developer menu.</Text>
        <Button title="click me to see profiling in console log" onPress={()=> this._setIndex(2)}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
...
```

Make sure `Remote Debug JS` is on, then you can see the results on chrome console.

Comment: I would add a warning though: make sure that `PerfMonitor.toggle()` is called only once. I would call it outside of `_setIndex`

Comment: @AmauryLiet This is a very good point. You can put `PerfMonitor.toggle()` in `componentWillMount()`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try enabling the performance monitor in the dev menu by clicking on Show Perf Monitor?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5Hpq.jpg)